# how to determine checkboxlist is checked/selected -

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i execute the code i get 4 checkboxs and i checked/selected all 4 checkbox and when i try to debug the code, it does count that i have 4 checkbox but all 4 checkbox is selected=false.

what i am missing in code?

```
<asp:checkboxlist id="chk" runat="server" ondatabinding="chk_DataBinding"
   ondatabound="chk_DataBound">
</asp:checkboxlist>

List<String> roles = new List<string>();

 for (int i = 0; i < chk.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     if (chk.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        roles.Add(chk.Items[i].Value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't clear supposed to remove all elements? Are you even getting into that for loop?

Comment: i updated my question, yes it going into loop but it says i haven not selected any checkbox (in fact i have checked all the checkbox)

Comment: I'm confused.  You are looping through the checkboxlist items and if an item is selected you are adding that value back into the checkboxlist?

Comment: i am not adding into checkboxlist, please see my question.

Comment: Well you keep editing it and changing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is consistent with the basic `CheckBoxList` given on the [`ListControl.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) page, and from personal experience, checking the `.Selected` property of the `ListItem` should work fine.

Check to make sure you aren't re-populating the `CheckBoxList` before you hit the "if checked" logic - if I had to guess, I'd say there's a good chance you're losing the list on every postback.  The simple solution is don't call your databinding logic if it's a postback.

Comment: i place an breakpoint on databinding and it only goes when the page loads and after i click the button (postback) it does not go to databinding event.

Comment: Is it possible that you are adding or removing event handlers from the code behind as well, or that there is another bit of logic to remove and add check boxes without databinding?  Besides that, if you look at the `CheckBoxList` in `Page.PreLoad` or at the beginning of `Page.Load`, do you see any selected `ListItems`?

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I forgot IsPostBack!

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] CheckboxListSelections(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList list)
{
 ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
 for(int counter = 0; counter < list.Items.Count; counter++)
 {
  if(list.Items[counter].Selected)
  {
   values.Add(list.Items[counter].Value);
  }    
 }
 return (String[]) values.ToArray( typeof( string ) );
}
```