# How to validate checkbox list in content page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I am taking a checkbox list in content page of a master page by which i can select multiple values and save in the database. How to confirm that minimum one of the checkboxes r selected at the time of clicking the submit button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129445/how-to-determine-checkboxlist-is-checked-selected

Comment: do you want validation in java-script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below.

**It does not matter in JavaScript that where control are either or content page or master page**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkModuleList"runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvmodulelist"
  ClientValidationFunction="ValidateModuleList"
  ErrorMessage="Please Select Atleast one Module" />

// javascript to add to your aspx page
function ValidateModuleList(source, args)
{
  var chkListModules= document.getElementById ('<%= chkModuleList.ClientID %>');
  var chkListinputs = chkListModules.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0;i<chkListinputs .length;i++)
  {
    if (chkListinputs [i].checked)
    {
      args.IsValid = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = false;
}
```

**Update:**
Or you can go through this approach: Put any `css-class` say `company`. You can go through below.

There is a `:checked` ( http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ ) selector you can use :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".company input").click(function() {
            var cnt = $(".company input:checked").length;
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
               // none checked
            }
            else
            {
               // any checked
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**You may want to add (or use) an id on the container of these checkbox, to optimize selector speed.**

As for asp.net messing up client ids on controls, you can use

```
$('<%= MyControl.ClientID %>')
```

References:

- [Check if a checkbox is checked in a group of checkboxes in clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529319/check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-group-of-checkboxes-in-clientside)
- [How to validate a user chose at least one checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146234/asp-net-checkboxlist-how-to-validate-a-user-choose-at-least-one-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

[Dado.Validators](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.Validators), a library on GitHub, handles this very nicely too.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCheckBoxList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box (empty)" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 3" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<Dado:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="cblCheckBoxList" ValidationGroup="vlgSubmit" />
```

Example codebehind.aspx.cs

```
btnSubmit.Click += (a, b) =>
{
    Page.Validate("vlgSubmit");
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        // Validation Successful
    }
};
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dado.Validators/